# Set property on body using bean()

Tags: apache-camel

I'm trying to set a property called "articleId" on the exchange's body and I thought the most explicit way to do this would be to use `bean()`.  However, I can't get it to work.  When I have the following in my route:

```
.bean(body(Article.class), "setArticleId(${header.articleId})")
```

I get this error message:

> Caused by: org.apache.camel.component.bean.MethodNotFoundException: Method with name: setArticleId(${header.articleId}) not found on bean: bodyAs[com.example.model.Article] of type: org.apache.camel.builder.ValueBuilder

My solution has been to use a `processor()` and a few lines of code in order to set the articleId property from the header value, but to me that seems like overkill.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've been complaining on camel-users that there isn't a good way to do this. For now here is how I tackle it:

```
.setHeader("dummy").ognl("request.body.articleId = request.headers.articleId")
```

Which requires adding camel-ognl dependency.

### UPDATE

Actually, there is also a language endpoint that can do this without the setHeader, but you have to say transform=false or else it replaces your body with the result:

```
.to("language:ognl:request.body.articleId = request.headers.articleId?transform=false") // remember ?transform=false
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to spend some time to go through [this page](http://camel.apache.org/bean-binding.html), if you don't know how to tell camel which method of the bean you want it invoke.

If you just want to set the exchange property, you can just use the DSL

> setProperty("articleId", body());

to do this kind of work.

Comment: I had read that page, that's how I came up with my current scheme.  Essentially my Exchange has a Body that encloses an Article POJO.  On that Article POJO I have an "articleId" property setter.  What I'd like to do is set that `articleId` property with the value of an exchange header (namely `articleId`)

Comment: You can just pass the body and exchange into you Bean method.